# How to avoid using select in ranges VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running main Sub which works fine. At the end of Main() I'm calling sub to do other thing to clean up code of Main.

```vb
Sub DragDown()
    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dane")
    
    Dim LRs As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LRs = TargetWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = TargetWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
    
    TargetWS.Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(LastRow, 30)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=TargetWS.Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(LRs, 30)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Both subs are saved in same Module, but DragDown() crash at  `TargetWS.Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(LastRow, 30)).Select` with error 1004 method range of object _worksheet failed.

So how to fix this? Or how to get rid of .select method?

I tried to use something like  `Dim rng as Range Set rng = Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(LastRow, 30))` but it doesn't seem to work...

Edit:
SOLVED! by VBasic2008 in comments

````vb
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = TargetWS.Range(TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 25), TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 30))
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = TargetWS.Range(TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 25), TargetWS.Cells(LRs, 30))
    srg.AutoFill Destination:=drg, Type:=xlFillDefault```
````

Comment: You need to qualify the `Cells` calls with `TargetWS`.

Comment: Why don't you use variables: `Dim srg As Range` : `Set srg = TargetWS.Range(TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 25), TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 30))` : `Dim drg As Range` : `Set drg = TargetWS.Range(TargetWS.Cells(LastRow, 25), TargetWS.Cells(LRs, 30))` : `srg.AutoFill Destination:=drg, Type:=xlFillDefault`. Btw, in the rare cases when you need to `Select` a range (cell), you have to make sure that the right worksheet is active: e.g. `TargetWS.Activate` : `srg.Select` : `Range("A1").Select`. You could benefit from reading [`How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251).

Comment: Thank you @VBasics2008 this works like a charm! I've read linked question but now I understand my mistake :)